# ZeroMQ XPub-XSub with PHP: Messages never arrive at proxy

Tags: php, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to implement Publish Subscribe using a Proxy with ZeroMQ and PHP [as it is described in the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Dynamic-Discovery-Problem) in Figure 13. The setup is the same as described here: [how to implement Pub-Sub Network with a Proxy by using XPUB and XSUB in ZeroMQ(jzmq) 3.xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516102/how-to-implement-pub-sub-network-with-a-proxy-by-using-xpub-and-xsub-in-zeromqj)

**subscriber.php**

```
<?php
$context = new ZMQContext();
$sub = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_SUB);
$sub->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
$sub->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_SUBSCRIBE, 'Hello');
$msg = $sub->recv();
echo "got $msg";
```

**publisher.php**

```
<?php

$context = new ZMQContext();
$pub = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB);
$pub->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:6000");

while (1) {
    echo "publishing";
    $pub->send("Hello World");
    sleep(1);
}
```

**proxy.php**

```
<?php
$context = new ZMQContext();
$frontend = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_XSUB);
$frontend->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:6000");
$backend = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_XPUB);
$backend->bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
$device = new ZMQDevice($frontend, $backend);
$device->run();
```

If I start all three PHP scripts (first proxy, then publisher, then subscriber) no messages arrive at that subscriber.

In order to see if any messages arrive at the proxy at all, I tried to receive the messages manually on the proxy:

```
while (true) {
    if ($frontend->recv(ZMQ::MODE_DONTWAIT)) {
        echo "received message from xpub";
    }
    if ($frontend->recv(ZMQ::MODE_DONTWAIT)) {
        echo "received message from xsub";  
    }
}
```

There are serveral related questions on Stack Overflow:

- [How to implement Pub-Sub Network with a Proxy by using XPUB and XSUB in ZeroMQ(C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570810/how-to-implement-pub-sub-network-with-a-proxy-by-using-xpub-and-xsub-in-zeromqc) - I am using the proxy as described in the answer, but I still don't receive any messages. Therefore this question does not apply
- [how to implement Pub-Sub Network with a Proxy by using XPUB and XSUB in ZeroMQ(jzmq) 3.xx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516102/how-to-implement-pub-sub-network-with-a-proxy-by-using-xpub-and-xsub-in-zeromqj) The person who answered said the problem was that messages from the publisher were not forwarded to the subscriber. However, I don't receive any messages from the publisher at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly XSUB-scribe the [ PROXY ] to any topic: `$frontend->send( ( ascii 1 ) + "" ); /* XSUBSCRIBE to ANY topic incoming */ ` ? ( **API-Ref.: >>>** http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-socket#toc12 )

Comment: That's it! I added `$frontend->send(chr(1));` to the proxy and it works. Please feel free to convert this to an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad it helped. Salutes to Vienna ( nice homepage :o) )

Comment: Thanks! Best wishes to Prague :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [PROXY] needs to have the topic-filter set too:

`$frontend->send( chr(1) + "" ); /* XSUBSCRIBE to { ANY == "" } topic incoming */`

> <sub>( For ZeroMQ API-Ref.: >>> [ZeroMQ API documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3Azmq-socket#toc12) )</sub>